# Prove $\sin(\alpha/n)$ and $\cos(\alpha/n)$ are algebraic over $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sin\alpha)$ for any positive integer $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I observed that $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ are clearly algebraic over K. I'm not sure if I should use induction on this one because I would have to somehow deal with $\sin\frac{\alpha}{n-1}$ and $\cos\frac{\alpha}{n-1}$. In any case, I need to show that I can write $\sin(\alpha/n)=P(\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)$ for $P \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ and the same with $\cos(\alpha/n)$. I was thinking of using the identity $$\sin(nx)=Im [(\cos x+i\sin x)^n]$$ and then let $x=\alpha/n$, but then I would have to deal with all the cosine terms, which I can't assume they're algebraic over $K$. What are useful identities that I can use here?

Comment: Lol are you in Topaz's 114 class?

Comment: See [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use
$$
2i\sin x = e^x-e^{-x} \qquad 2\cos x= e^x+e^{-x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use just $\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 = 1$, there are two polynomials $P$ and $Q$ with integer coefficients that 
$$\sin(nx) = P(\sin(x))\cos(x) + Q(\sin(x))$$
Put $Q$ on the left side and raise it to square power. You obtain a polynomial with integer coefficient having $\sin(nx)$ and $\sin(x)$ as variables. And $\cos(x)$ is at most second order extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sin(x))$, it is easy to conclude.

Comment: How do you know polynomials $P$ and $Q$ exist?

Comment: Using exactly the formula you wrote above, expand the power $n$, and replace all the $\cos(x)^2$ by $1-\sin(x)^2$, therefore the only term you cannot replace will be $\cos(x)$.